# Spinning a balanced load with DC motor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, manufacturing-engineering, friction

Enclosed within a consumer electronic, I would like to spin a small balanced load.  The device will be rotated relative to gravity, but no other direct forces will be applied to the load.  A coreless DC motor (e.g. often used for pager vibrators) will be used, but in contrast I would like to minimize noise/vibration.  Here is what a current prototype looks like:

[image]

If I just hang the bare motor by its wire leads and let it spin the balanced load, there is low noise/friction relative to the above assembly.  I believe this is because the above assembly adds rotation resistance via the shaft hole and acts as a 'vibrational conduit' to the motor.  However, because the device will be rotated w.r.t. to gravity, and the load is of moderate mass (2-4g), I think there will need to be some sort of shaft support to prevent radial play.  There are two basic designs I can think of to achieve this:

1. External shaft hole (as seen in above image)
2. Bi-axial motor (seen below):

[image]

The main criteria to decide between the two should be:

- low noise/vibration
- low axial/radial play
- easy to assemble/difficult to incorrectly assemble

Given these criteria, it seems to me that using a biaxial motor is the way to go.  However, there is one catch: they are not commonly produced, and I can only find one [source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MRIF4RT).  Furthermore, the only model I could find operates at 24V (vs typical 3.7V), which will require stepping up logic voltages.  So, if using a biaxial motor is indeed preferable for this application, would it be reasonable to expect a manufacturer to make me 'custom' biaxial 3.7V motors of quantity 5-10K?  If such a customization is not feasible for this relatively low order quantity, does it make more sense to develop a shaft support assembly for a uniaxial motor, or work around the non-ideal electrical characteristics of the 24V biaxial motor?

Comment: What RPM do you require? One method to reduce noise and vibrations is to run the motor at voltage considerably lower than rated, producing significantly lower RPM. This also reduces load and stress on all elements, allowing for the motor to take much more "abuse" than when operating at nominal power.

Comment: @SF I want to run it at ~10kRPM whereas these motors typically have ~50kRPM with no load at rated voltage.  For instance, I may only need a voltage of ~1V for  a 3.7V motor.  However, this will be the same regardless of what "shaft support" method is used.